# OpenXml and Word: How to Calculate WrapPolygon Coordinates?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am creating a Microsoft Word document using the OpenXml library. Most of what I need is already working correctly. However, I can't for the life of me find the following bit of information.

I'm displaying an image in an anchor, which causes text to wrap around the image. I used `WrapSquare` but this seems to affect the last line of the *previous* paragraph as shown in the image below. The image is anchored to the second paragraph but causes the last line of the first paragraph to also indent around the image.

[Word Screenshot http://www.softcircuits.com/Client/Word.jpg](http://www.softcircuits.com/Client/Word.jpg)

Experimenting within Word, I can make the text wrap how I want by changing the wrapping to `WrapTight`. However, this requires a `WrapPolygon` with several coordinates. And I can't find any way to determine the polygon coordinates so that they match the size of the image, which is in pixels.

The documentation doesn't even seem to indicate what units are used for these coordinates, let alone how to calculate them from pixels. I can only assume the calculation would involve a DPI value, but I have no idea how to determine what DPI will be used when the user eventually loads the document into Word.

I would also be satisfied if someone can explain why the issues described above is happening in the first place. I can shift the image down and the previous paragraph is no longer affected. But why is this necessary? (The Distance from text setting for both Left and Top is 0".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved this. Despite what the standard says, the `WrapPolygon` coordinates are *not* EMUs (English Metric Units). The coordinates are relative to the fixed coordinate space (21600 x 21600, as mentioned in the quote provided by amurra).

More specifically, this means 0,0 is at the top, left corner of the image, and 21600,21600 is at the bottom, right corner of the image. This is the case no matter what the size of the image is. Coordinates greater than 21600 extend outside the image.

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342530%28v=office.12%29.aspx), "The 21600 value is a legacy artifact from the drawing layer of early versions of the Microsoft Office."

Answer (score 2):

The `WrapPolygon` element has two possible child elements of `LineTo` and `StartPoint` that each take a x and y coordinate. According to **2.1.1331 Part 1 Section 20.4.2.9, lineTo (Wrapping Polygon Line End Position)** and **2.1.1334 Part 1 Section 20.4.2.14, start (Wrapping Polygon Start)** found in the [[MS-OI29500: Microsoft Office Implementation Information for ISO/IEC-29500 Standard Compliance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee908652%28v=office.12%29.aspx)]:

> The standard states that the x and y attributes are represented in
>   EMUs. Office interprets the x and y attributes in a fixed coordinate
>   space of 21600x21600.

As far as converting pixels to EMUs (English Metric Units), take a look at this [blog](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/points-inches-and-emus-measuring-units-in-office-open-xml/) post for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the reference that states these coordinates are represented in EMUs. I had been using ECMA-376 as a reference and it didn't appear to provide this information. With respect to the blog post, I'm familiar with this one. It does show how to convert pixels to a value based on inches (as EMUs are); however, it assumes a DPI of 72. As I understand it, DPI can be values like 72, 96, 300, or even 1200.

Comment: BTW, that last sentence from the Microsoft documentation doesn't make any sense to me. A coordinate space of 21600x21600 EMUs is less than an inch. I'm missing some part of this.